# This tag should be [increment]ally removed

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I do not find [increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/increment) very useful. It has 2000+ Questions but 0 followers.

Comment: What value is to be gained from *removing* it?  Is it in any way *harmful* to have?

Comment: It's not useful... noise.

Comment: The noise created from going through and editing all of those questions is likely to be *more* disruptive, not to mention a far less efficient use of time than so many other possible moderation activities.

Comment: Am not sure. They are not really related.

Comment: I increment the score of this - not only is the wiki entry garbage, I can't ever see how adding this tag to a question would help it be solved better.

Comment: It's the name of an operator in most languages, so I doubt we should completely get rid of it, but it definitely needs a clean-up.

Comment: @BilltheLizard in that case I think it should maybe be prefixed with the language in question to be more useful. At the moment, no one is subscribed to the tag, showing how useful it is.

Comment: @Tshepang The language-specific tags wouldn't have any followers either. That's not really a reason to blacklist a tag. There's a really small number of situations where the increment operator is going to behave in an unexpected way, so I'd expect it to have only a handful of questions and no followers.

Comment: Please give a read to the tag info page for the [blacklist-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/blacklist-request/info) tag, and read the linked blog post. There is a high bar for blacklisting tags, since it's something only community managers (employees of SO) can do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little ambivalent about this one because, at first glance at least, it seems absurdly narrow. With that said, its tag Wiki is unambiguous and on-topic:

> Adding one to the value of a variable, generally with the use of an increment operator.

Also, a sampling of the questions shows that a lot of them are legitimately about problems with incrementing variables.

That being said, I don't think that this tag really meets burnination criteria.